# C++ Linked List BreakPoint Error with deletion

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Hey I'm trying to make a linked list that times how long it takes to add elements just from the beginning and just from the end. Then delete then from the beginning and from the end. I have the code for adding and deleting but I'm getting a breakpoint error referring to memory allocation when I delete the final element from the list. I'm guessing I need to add a a failsafe for when the list is empty but I can't work out how to do it.

Some advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm very new to this.

Thanks!

**My code for the list class:**

```
class list
{
public:
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node* next;
    } *head, *tail;

    list() :head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}   // constructor  

    ~list() {
        node* current, * temp;
        current = head;
        temp = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = current;
        }
    }

    // adding to the end of list  
    void addToEnd(int n) {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = n;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }
        node* cur = head;
        while (cur) {
            if (cur->next == NULL) {
                cur->next = newNode;
                return;
            }
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    
    //Add to beginning
    void addToBeginning(int n) {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = n;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else {
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        
    }

    void deleteFromBeginning() {
        if (head != NULL) {
            node* temp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
        }
        if (head == NULL) {
            cout << "Nothing to delete" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    void deleteFromEnd() {
        node* removeLastNode = head;
            if (head == NULL)
                return;

            if (head->next == NULL) {
                delete head;
                return;
            }

            // Find the second last node 
            node* second_last = head;
            while (second_last->next->next != NULL)
                second_last = second_last->next;

            // Delete last node 
            delete (second_last->next);

            // Change next of second last 
            second_last->next = NULL;

        }

    //Display List
    void displayList() {
        if (head != NULL) {
// This was also triggering an access violation error when I tried to run this after the delete loop
            for (node* temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) { 
                cout << temp->data << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

};
```

I want to keep this in a seperate class as it will be part of a bigger program and I want to minimise the code on the main source file.

**Here is the code for the main:**

```
int main() {
    int data;
    list myList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        myList.addToBeginning(i);
    }
    myList.displayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myList.deleteFromBeginning();
    }
    myList.displayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myList.addToEnd(i);
    }
    myList.displayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        myList.deleteFromEnd(); // Error comes here
    }
}
```

Comment: *"a breakpoint error"* -- no such thing. You probably mean that you were running this in a debugger, and the debugger interrupted the execution when a serious error (a likely crash) was detected. *Good news, everyone! Since you are using a debugger, you can inspect the values of variables to get a better picture of what went wrong.*

Comment: Please work on a smaller [mre]. You suspect that removing the final element is problematic. So trim your `main` function down to adding a *single* element to the list, then deleting that element. If the crash persists, get rid of all code not needed to support this more minimal `main()`. ***Exception:** You might want to review `deleteFromBeginning()` before removing it from the example. You do a few things in that function that are missing from `deleteFromEnd()`.*

Comment: Have trimmed it down, possibly I'm not fully understanding how the pointers are working here. This is the message I'm still getting: Exception thrown: read access violation.
second_last->next was nullptr.

Comment: nevermind, I have worked it out. Had to check if list has more than one item then start the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Had to check if list has more than one item then start the while loop. It was causing an issue when I had only 1 node left.

```
void deleteFromEnd() {
            node* temp;
            if (head == NULL)
            {
                cout << " There is no item to delete!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            node* start = head;
            if (start->next != NULL)
            {
                while ((start->next)->next != NULL)
                {
                    start = start->next;
                }
                temp = start->next;
                start->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = start;
                head = NULL;
            }
            delete temp;
        }
```

Comment: Your fix looks good, but your analysis is off. The version of this function in the question also skips the loop if the list has only one item, via the line `if (head->next == NULL)`. So that change is not a fix. The key improvement in this answer is that you update `head` (by assigning `head = NULL`) when deleting the last item in the list.